# Redux saga. unable to use yield in a promise 'catch' block

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I am pretty new to redux-saga and am getting the error **yield is a reserved word in strict mode** only inside the axios promise below. I do **not** get this error on the second try/catch

```
function* usernameLoginWorker({ username, password, rememberMe }) {
  try {
    axios
      .post('login', { username, password, rememberMe })
      .then(handleUsernameLogin)
      .catch(error => {
        yield put(actions.loginError(GENERAL_ERRORS.LOGIN)); < ERROR HERE
      });
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(actions.loginError(GENERAL_ERRORS.LOGIN));
  }
}
```

Obviously I can refactor that one line and replace with

```
store.dispatch(actions.loginError(error));
```

but that's a hack. any insight/alternative would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can yield a Promise in a saga and it will wait for it to finish or it will go to the `catch` block if it fails. You can rewrite your code like this:

```
function* usernameLoginWorker({ username, password, rememberMe }) {
  try {
    const result = yield axios.post('login', { username, password, rememberMe });
    yield call(handleUsernameLogin, result);
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(actions.loginError(GENERAL_ERRORS.LOGIN));
  }
}
```